# How to use a Swift class from Source folder in Swift2 playground

Tags: swift2

This problem has occurred in Xcode 7.0.1. How do I use a public class from the Source folder in my Swift playground?

```
import Foundation
public class User {
    var name: String = ""
    var age: Int = 0
    init (name: String, age: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
}
```

In the main playground (below), I get error *'User' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers*.

```
import Cocoa
let user1 = User(name: "User", age: 99)
```

Evidence of my folder structure is in this screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you that the `init` is not accessible. Make it public, too.

Comment: Thank you. I had tried your suggested change previously. I think I just needed to give more time to the compiler. I'm new to Swift - it's all very unfamiliar, especially the playground environment for prototyping.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class User {
    var name: String?
    var age: Int?
    init (name: String, age: Int) 
     {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't solve or progress the problem.

Comment: did you try it ? and what do you mean by that ?

Comment: I tried it, and what I mean is the same error message occurs after implementing your suggested change. You try it.

Comment: that's weird because I just ran the code and it works